# which range loop(auto, auto&, const auto&) is more efficient in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class One
{
public:
    One(int age, int price)
        : m_age(age), m_price(price)
    {
        std::cout << "m_age: " << m_age << " , m_price: " << m_price << std::endl;    
    }
    One(const One&) = default;
    One& operator=(const One&) = default;

    int age() const { return m_age; }
    int price() const { return m_price; }

private:
    int m_age;
    int m_price;    
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const One& one)
{
    os << "<< m_age: " << one.age() << " , m_price: " << one.price();
    return os;    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<One> vecOnes = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

    //for(auto it: vecOnes)                // case I
    //for(auto& it: vecOnes)         // case II
    for(const auto& it: vecOnes)           // case III
    {
        std::cout << it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

All three cases output the same results as follows:

```
m_age: 1 , m_price: 2
m_age: 3 , m_price: 4
<< m_age: 1 , m_price: 2
<< m_age: 3 , m_price: 4
```

Question> which case is more efficient way to use `auto`?
Originally, I expect the auto will trigger the constructor of class One. But it doesn't show that way based on the output results.

Comment: `I expect the auto will trigger the constructor of class One. But it doesn't show that way based on the output results.` Your class has two constructors, but you've only instrumented one. It's the other one - the copy constructor - that gets called, and it doesn't produce any output. Implement it to print something if you want to see it in action.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Igor answers belong as answers

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't edit answers into your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Originally, I expect the auto will trigger the constructor of class One. But it doesn't show that way based on the output results.

It does trigger a constructor: the copy constructor. But you didn't instrument that one<sup>†</sup> so you don't see any output. The other two cases don't construct a new object, so will definitely be more efficient.

Note that there is also a fourth case `for (auto&& it : vecOnes) {...}` It will be equivalent to your second case here and also not create any new objects.

<sup>†</sup>Well now that you edited your question, it should be pretty clear that the one case does construct new objects and the others all do not.

Answer (score 0):

The reality is, it depends...

If you've just got a vector of a built-in type, such as an `int` then you might as well use `auto it` as it's cheap to make a copy and you'll save a dereference every time you use the value. For classes this will invoke the copy constructor which may affect performance.

However, if you're vector is contains a class then in general it'll be more efficient to use `auto &it` or `const auto &it` in order to save creating a copy of the object. There's no cost advantage to using `const` over non-`const`, it just comes down to how you want to interact with the object.